# почему windows не хочет работать в карманном режиме?

Tags: windows, ssd

у меня несколько рабочих ноутбуков, хочу сделать переносную виндовс (как на флешке), купил  карман asus rog strix arion, вот только когда поставил с компа в карман ssd, то компьютер выдает inaccessible boot device.
если я переустановлю виндовс уже будь ссд в кармане, поможет ли это в данной ситуации? вставил в ноут или десктоп карман с ссд, выбрал в биос и загрузился...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: винда не очень хорошо реагирует на смену железа. Боюсь ваша затея немного сложна в реализации. Линукс в данном случае поступает толерантнее.

Comment: Для такого сценария есть Windows To Go.

Comment: у меня до этого с другим ssd получалось, правда я использовал только с одним железом, вот и вопрос, есть ли смысл форматировать этот диск, дабы снова связка работала